# How can I validate a hash generated by Flask-Security without using it?

Tags: python, hash, sha512, pbkdf2, flask-security

I have a Flask application running that has Flask-Security on it. My `config.py` file looks like this:

```py
...

# Flask-Security config
SECURITY_URL_PREFIX = "..." # my URL prefix
SECURITY_PASSWORD_HASH = "pbkdf2_sha512"
SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT = "..." # my 29-character long salt

...
```

and it generates a hash like this on the database:

> `$pbkdf2-sha512$25000$pXROaU2JUSrlnDPm3BsjBA$ckspsls2SWPhl9dY7XDiAZh5yucWq27fWRuVj4aOUc5dA2Ez5VH1LYiz5KjaZJscaJYAFhWIwPhkAsHiPOrvrg`

which is the password `123456` hashed.

In another application, I needed this hash to be verified, but by using Flask-Security it demands me to be in a Flask application with the same configurations set.
I've tried many things but I just can't validate this password without Flask-Security and there MUST be a way of doing that.
Can you guys please help me on this?

Comment: You don't say what you have tried. Basically - you need to look at the source and copy relevant pieces from utils.py::verify_password(). Note that by default, Flask-Security does a double hash, so you will need to copy get_hmac(). And of course setup a passlib context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so thanks to @jwag and few more digging on the Flask-Security source code, I've managed to do it.

For those on the same situation, here's what I did:

```py
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
from passlib.context import CryptContext

text_type = str
salt = "YOUR_SALT_HERE"

def get_pw_context ():
  pw_hash = 'pbkdf2_sha512'
  schemes = ['bcrypt', 'des_crypt', 'pbkdf2_sha256', 'pbkdf2_sha512', 'sha256_crypt', 'sha512_crypt', 'plaintext']
  deprecated = ['auto']
  return CryptContext (schemes=schemes, default=pw_hash, deprecated=deprecated)

def encode_string(string):
  if isinstance(string, text_type):
    string = string.encode('utf-8')
  return string

def get_hmac (password):
  h = hmac.new(encode_string(salt), encode_string(password), hashlib.sha512)
  return base64.b64encode(h.digest())

def verify_password (password, hash):
  return get_pw_context().verify(get_hmac(password), hash)

# Finally
verify_password ("MY_PASSWORD", "MY_PASSWORD_HASH")
```